# Changes associated with Git Bash and activating conda env

Tags: bash, conda, git-bash, mingw-w64, msys2

When activating my conda environment in Git Bash (mingw64) by running `source activate myenv`, I've noticed some odd changes.

For example:

- The `ls -l` command is the equivalent of just `ls`

  - I am unable to see permissions on each file or any other info that is expected from `ls -l`
- Bash scripts that work in base environment no longer work after activating my conda environment

  - Simple things like running for loops using `seq` doesn't work
  - Commands to convert datetime to integer dates no longer work

Does activating a conda env change something regarding bash shell?

UPDATE:
Tried using `conda activate myenv` per merv's suggestion. It didn't work initially since I had never used it. After running `conda init`, I was able to activate my environment using `conda activate myenv`. I was also able to deactivate my env -- which was something I was having trouble with before.

The issues I have, however, are not remedied with `conda activate`. The `ls -l` command still does not output correctly.

Here is the output of `conda info`. Name of the env is actually `eda`.:

```
$ conda info

         active environment : eda
        active env location : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\eda
                shell level : 2
           user config file : C:\Users\user\.condarc
     populated config files : C:\Users\user\.condarc
              conda version : 4.6.8
        conda-build version : 3.17.6
             python version : 3.7.1.final.0
           base environment : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
               channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                              https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
                              https://conda.anaconda.org/bokeh/win-64
                              https://conda.anaconda.org/bokeh/noarch
                              https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                              https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
              package cache : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
                              C:\Users\user\.conda\pkgs
                              C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
           envs directories : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
                              C:\Users\user\.conda\envs
                              C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                   platform : win-64
                 user-agent : conda/4.6.8 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.1 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.14393
              administrator : True
                 netrc file : None
               offline mode : False
```

Comment: updating with `conda info` output

Comment: Thanks. Yes this sounds strange. Is there a difference between `which ls` when deactivated vs activated?

Comment: Yep. `which ls` in base env outputs: `/usr/bin/ls`. After `conda activate`, output is `/c/Users/wkong/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/eda/Library/usr/bin/ls`

Comment: Looks like you installed some package in that env which includes a new `ls`. I know `coreutils` has an `ls`, but that's the GNU version, so it would have `ls -l` functionality. What does `man ls` tell you?

Comment: Interesting. `man` doesn't work in Git Bash, but `ls --help` provides documentation on `ls` if in base env. After activating conda env, however, `ls --help` outputs the equivalent of `ls`.

Comment: Maybe you can post the `conda list -n eda` and someone can spot the offending package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with `conda activate` and running

```
echo '. ${HOME}/.bash_profile' >> ~/.bashrc
```

in Git bash helped. After that, you need to insert

```
auto_activate_base: false
```

in your `.condarc` file, restart your Git bash terminal, and you should have it running, without any environment activated automatically. (At least I had to use various environments and didn't want base to be active on opening the terminal)
I wonder if this helps?

I used https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114257/why-does-base-appear-in-front-of-my-terminal-prompt-ii

Comment: not really an issue for me anymore and no longer on a windows machine to check